# How to change size font of the title of the chart with PhpExcel or PhpSpreadSheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

```
$title= new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Title("titulo",$layout);

$chart = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart(
    'chart1',   // name
    $title,       // title
    $legend,       // legend
    $plotArea,  // plotArea
    true,       // plotVisibleOnly
    0,          // displayBlanksAs
    $xAxisLabel,       // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel        // yAxisLabel
);
```

This code set parameters to generate a chart in a file of excel.
By default the size font of the title of the chart is 18pt. I want to change the size to 10pt.
How can I do it?